# Using lambda expression from a child class

Tags: c#, lambda, asp.net-core-2.1

I have following situation:

```
public class BaseClass
{
public string Field1 { get; set; }
public string Field2 { get; set; }
public string Field3 { get; set; }    
}

public class Product: BaseClass
{
/* Some methods*/
}

public class Country: BaseClass
{
/* Some methods*/
}

public class MyCustomClass
{
public Product Product { get; set; }
public Country Country { get; set; }    
}
```

I want to create a list of expressions which I would later use to query my `MyCustomClass`, example

```
var listOfExpressions= new List<Expression<Func<MyCustomClass, bool>>>();

if (x == 1)
    listOfExpressions.Add(x => x.Product.Field1 == "Fruit")
/*.
  .
  .*/
if (y == 2)
    listOfExpressions.Add(x => x.Country.Field2 == "Western")
}
```

Now this looks really ugly with these bunch of Ifs and I would prefer to have a method in `BaseClass` for which you would pass `int` (`{1,2,3}`) and it would return me the expression. The problem is that I need to have expression of type `<MyCustomClass, bool>` but in my `BaseClass` I can't directly get that, is there an way I could acheive this without complicating code too much?

I am thinking about something like this:

```
public class BaseClass
{
public string Field1 { get; set; }
public string Field2 { get; set; }
public string Field3 { get; set; }    

protected Expression<Func<BaseClass, bool>> GetExpression(int key, string value)
{
        switch (key)
        {
            case 1:
                return x => x.Field1 == value;
            case 2:
                return x => x.Field2 == value;
            case 3:
                return x => x.Field3 == value;
        }
}
```

By now I am stuck of how to get `Expression<Func<BaseClass, bool>>` to be used in `Expression<Func<MyCustomClass, bool>>`.

EDIT: The purpose of the expression:

I want to constuct a list of expressions to later use it to query database using Entity framework core. Example:

```
    var query = DbContext.MyCustomClass.AsQueryable();

    foreach (var expression in listOfExpressions)
    {
        query = query.Where(expression);
    }
```

Comment: Could you elaborate what the actual problem you try to solve is? Why you need the Expression for example

Comment: I don't see what you get from moving into the base class.  You still have branching logic (switch vs. if).  Why not put it into `MyCustomClass` instead?

Comment: @X39 I have updated the question with the example why I want expressions. By moving it to base class I would need it to write just once (all derived classes use same logic), hence less maintenance

Comment: [Favour composition over inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance). I'd just add a helper method and call that. Inheritance almost always becomes a rod for your own back.

Comment: It still did not explained what the actual problem is.. What are you trying to archive exactly, word the whole problem, not only parts of it. Why you want to query a list of expressions against EF for example is not clear. With the proper question asked, a proper answer may follow. Right now, it still is not clear to me what you want to archive exactly with that approach and why those weird number sare in use.
*Start at the beginning and not inbetween*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build your Expression on you own. Just add another parameter to `GetExpression`:

```
public static Expression<Func<MyCustomClass, bool>> GetExpression(
    string derrivedName, // "Product" or "Country"
    int fieldId,
    string value)
{
    var x = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MyCustomClass), "x");
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<MyCustomClass, bool>>(
        Expression.Equal(
            Expression.Constant(value),
            Expression.PropertyOrField(
                Expression.PropertyOrField(x, derrivedName),
                $"Field{fieldId}")
            ), 
            x);

    return lambda;
}
```

Now you can use it like:

```
var exp3 = GetExpression("Product", 1, "Fruit");
```

This line will create an expression `x => ("Fruit" == x.Product.Field1)`